# Reading in a .txt file word by word to a struct in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, input, vector

I am having some trouble with my lab assignment for my CMPT class...
I am trying to read a text file that has two words and a string of numbers per line, and the file can be as long as anyone makes it.

An example is

```
Xiao Wang 135798642
Lucie Chan 122344566
Rich Morlan 123456789
Amir Khan 975312468
Pierre Guertin 533665789
Marie Tye 987654321
```

I have to make each line a separate "student", so I was thinking of using struct to do so, but I don't know how to do that as I need the first, last, and ID number to be separate.

```
struct Student{
    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    string idNumber;
};
```

All of the tries done to read in each word separately have failed (ended up reading the whole line instead) and I am getting mildly frustrated.

With the help from @Sylence I have managed to read in each line separately. I am still confused with how to split the lines by the whitespace though. Is there a split function in ifstream?
Sylence, is 'parts' going to be an array? I saw you had indexes in []'s.
What exactly does the `students.add( stud )` do?
My code so far is:

```
int getFileInfo()
{
    Student stdnt;
    ifstream stdntFile;
    string fileName;
    char buffer[256];
    cout<<"Please enter the filename of the file";
    cin>>filename;
    stdntFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    while(!stdFile.eof())
    {
        stdFile.getLine(buffer,100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my modified and final version of getFileInfo(), thank you Shahbaz, for the easy and quick way to read in the data.

```
void getFileInfo()
{
    int failed=0;
    ifstream fin;
    string fileName;
    vector<Student> students; // A place to store the list of students

Student s;                  // A place to store data of one student
cout<<"Please enter the filename of the student grades (ex. filename_1.txt)."<<endl;
do{
    if(failed>=1)
        cout<<"Please enter a correct filename."<<endl;
    cin>>fileName;
fin.open(fileName.c_str());// Open the file
failed++;
}while(!fin.good());
while (fin >> s.firstName >> s.lastName >> s.stdNumber)
    students.push_back(s);
fin.close();
cout<<students.max_size()<<endl<< students.size()<<endl<<students.capacity()<<endl;


return;
}
```

What I am confused about now is how to access the data that was inputted! I know it was put into a vector, but How to I go about accessing the individual spaces in the vector, and how exactly is the inputted data stored in the vector? If I try to cout a spot of the vector, I get an error because Visual Studio doesn't know what to output I guess..

Comment: Sorry, link to the txt file didn't work,

Comment: So what have you tried to do? Show us your efforts so we can help you along.

Comment: Alright.. thanks for the quick replies. I would gladly show you what I have so far, but I cannot figure out how to format the code in this comment box. Do I just put apostrophes around it or [code] or something? Sorry for being incompetent..

Comment: Modify your question. Don't put the code in the comments. There are buttons on top of the edit window. Select your code section and click on the code button (the quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are good, but they look a bit complicated. You can do it simply by:

```
vector<Student> students;   // A place to store the list of students

Student s;                  // A place to store data of one student

ifstream fin("filename");   // Open the file

while (fin >> s.firstName >> s.secondName >> s.idNumber)
    students.push_back(s);
```

Note that if `istream` fails, such as when the file finishes, the `istream` object (`fin`) will evaluate to `false`. Therefore `while (fin >> ....)` will stop when the file finishes.

P.S. Don't forget to check if the file is opened or not.

Comment: So how would I go about repeating this for the entire list of lines in the file and how would I tell it to make new student structs for each iteration??

Comment: Nice solution :) @b3orion you don't need to create a new object for each iteration since a vector uses a copy of the data you give.

Comment: Okay, So I don't need to create a new student each time, but for the loop, would I just use a while loop? I'm just confused how to tell it what line to use each iteration. As it stands now, without the loop, it only reads the last line of the file.

Comment: The `fin >> s.firstName >> s.secondName >> s.idNumber` reads one line of data from file and puts it in `s` which is a local variable of type `Student`. The `students.push_back(s)` makes a copy of `s` and puts in `students`. In the `while` loop, you keep reading lines, overwriting the same local variable `s` and adding a copy of it to `students`. Therefore, you get all the students. The loop stops when the file ends.

Comment: Okay, I get that now. Thanks for clearing that up! How would I go about finding where each student is stored. I mean, how do I access each individual student? This is my first time using vectors and structs, and file input! So this is a bit foggy for me! Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: How would I go about getting each student out of the `students` vector?

Comment: student `i` is in `students[i]`. To know how many students you have, get `students.size()`

Comment: You could search google for `c++ vector` and you get the complete reference

Answer (score 1):

Define a stream reader for student:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Student& data)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);

    std::stringstream   linestream(line);
    linestream >> data.firstName >> data.secondName >> data.idNumber;

    return stream;
}
```

Now you should be able to stream objects from any stream, including a file:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream    file("data");
    Student          student1;

    file >> student1;   // Read 1 student;

    // Or Copy a file of students into a vector
    std::vector<Student>   studentVector;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Student>(file),
              std::istream_iterator<Student>(),
              std::back_inserter(studentVector)
             );
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this work? Can you add some comments to the code please?

Comment: Since this is homework, I think it would be better if you teesed out the details for yourself. If you combine this information with @Shahbaz answer then you should have all the details you need.

Comment: But doesn't the code @Shahbaz already input the text read into Student? Why do I need a stream reader? I am confused as to how to access each student in the strcut though. How to I select each individual student as it put them in a vector...

Answer (score 0):

Simply read a whole line and then split the string at the spaces and assign the values to an object of the struct.

pseudo code:

```
while( !eof )
   line = readline()
   parts = line.split( ' ' )

   Student stud = new Student()
   stud.firstName = parts[0]
   stud.secondName = parts[1]
   stud.idNumber = parts[2]  

   students.add( stud )     
end while
```

Comment: This is actually all wrong (in so many ways). Please fix or I will downvote.

Comment: I have no problem with pseudo code. But you are breaking several critical rules. 1) don't test for eof in a while (applicable to all languages (as the EOF does not happen until you read past the EOF, which results in the loop being entered an extra time) 2) Don't use new especially when answering C++ questions. 3) splitting by space is OK in a lot of languages but actually leads you down the wrong path in C++